# Mysqli and real escape strings error

Tags: php

I'm converting old files to mysqli and am going along fine until I hit the mysql_real_escape_string. 
I'm getting the error message about not passing 2 parameters and understand that I'm only giving it one but can't figure out where to add the second one( I believe it is looking for the Db connection but at this point I've tried so many things I'm not sure anymore).
I thought I was good putting the Db connection in front of the $_POST command but that didn't work and gave me the 2 parameters error so if anyone could give me a nudge in the right direction I would appreciate it.

i

```
nclude "../connections/connect_mysqli.php";
    $conn = dbConnect('read'); 
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"; // query the person
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    $existCount = mysqli_num_rows($result); // count the row nums
if ($existCount == 0) { // evaluate the count
     echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database.";
     exit();
}
?>
<?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php 
// Delete Item Question to Admin, and Delete Product if they choose
if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
    echo 'Do you really want to delete product with ID of ' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '? <a href="inventory_list.php?yesdelete=' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '">Yes</a> | <a href="inventory_list.php">No</a>';
    exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
    // remove item from system and delete its picture
    // delete from database
    $id_to_delete = $_GET['yesdelete'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1" or die (mysqli_error());
    // unlink the image from server
    // Remove The Pic -------------------------------------------
    $pictodelete = ("../images/$id_to_delete.jpg");
    if (file_exists($pictodelete)) {
                unlink($pictodelete);
    }
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['product_name']);
    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
    $details = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
    $details2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['details2']);
    $details3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['details3']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name='$product_name' LIMIT 1";
    $productMatch = mysqli_num_rows($result); // count the output amount
    if ($productMatch > 0) {
        echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system, <a href="inventory_list.php">click here</a>';
        exit();
    }
    // Add this product into the database now
    $sql = ("INSERT INTO products (product_name, price, details, details2, details3, date_added) 
        VALUES('$product_name','$price','$details','$details2','$details3',now())") or die (mysqli_error());
     $pid = mysqli_insert_id();
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../images/$newname");
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: *"until I hit the mysql_real_escape_string"* - there is no code that suggests it and if you used the `i` version and passed the connection to it and what the connection really is. So, it's anyone's ballgame; I won't play (the guessing game) though as to what you are really using.

Comment: Sorry Fred, I thought I had it all copied.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real_escape_string method used in your example code but you are calling query method on $conn object which I think is mysqli connection. So you can use

```
$string = $conn->real_escape_string($string);
```

instead of mysql_real_escape_string. In fact you can use object methods and properties instead of mysqli functions. For example you can use

```
$result->num_rows
```

instead of mysqli_num_rows.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks sajushko, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues.

*Firstly,*

[`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) requires a database connection and as the first argument and followed by the POST array (or variable), where you only used it for one of them in your code.

```
$product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['product_name']);
                                          ^^^^^
```

and you need to do it for all of the rest below it.

You also didn't execute this query:

```
 $sql = "DELETE FROM products ....
```

nor this one:

```
$sql = ("INSERT INTO products ....
```

nor this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM products ...
```

I also noticed you may be storing passwords as plain text and this isn't safe to use in a live environment.

You should use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and a prepared statement is also a good thing.

Plus, [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) requires a db connection also:

```
mysqli_error($conn)
```

and make sure that all POST arrays do contain values.

Comment: Thanks Fred, I have been pounding at it for quite awhile and this fixed it for me. I had $conn in the escape strings but I took them out to start from scratch again. I thought the Db connection at the top of the page would carry through without adding it later and was wrong. I also missed the query execution after so many times of erasing and starting over. I use password hash on my regular site but this was a tutorial so I left it the way it was. I really appreciate the help. Cheers

Comment: @ribbonman You're welcome. If you wish to mark the question as solved, please do so. That way it will inform everyone that no other answers are required and closes the question, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

I like to post the finished code for any future beginners to help if they get in the same boat as me.

```
       include "../connections/connect_mysqli.php";
    $conn = dbConnect('read'); 
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"; // query the person
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
    // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    $existCount = $result->num_rows; // count the row nums
if ($existCount == 0) { // evaluate the count
     echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database.";
     exit();
}
?>
<?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php 
// Delete Item Question to Admin, and Delete Product if they choose
if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
    echo 'Do you really want to delete product with ID of ' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '? <a href="inventory_list.php?yesdelete=' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '">Yes</a> | <a href="inventory_list.php">No</a>';
    exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
    // remove item from system and delete its picture
    // delete from database
    $id_to_delete = $_GET['yesdelete'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
    // unlink the image from server
    // Remove The Pic -------------------------------------------
    $pictodelete = ("../images/$id_to_delete.jpg");
    if (file_exists($pictodelete)) {
                unlink($pictodelete);
    }
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $product_name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $price = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
    $details = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
    $details2 = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['details2']);
    $details3 = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['details3']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name='$product_name' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
    $productMatch = $result->num_rows; // count the output amount
    if ($productMatch > 0) {
        echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system, <a href="inventory_list.php">click here</a>';
        exit();
    }
    // Add this product into the database now
    $sql = ("INSERT INTO products (product_name, price, details, details2, details3, date_added) 
        VALUES('$product_name','$price','$details','$details2','$details3',now())") or die ($conn->error);
        $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
     $pid = $conn->insert_id;
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../images/$newname");
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```